# Setting margin-top to the height of the page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set the margin-top of a div to the height of the window minus 220px using JavaScript. I want this value to change whenever the window changes sizes.

Here is what I currently have:

HTML

```html
<body onresize="heroHeight()" onload="heroHeight()">
   <div class="heroImage"></div>
   <div class="content">
      <!-- page content -->
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```css
.content {
   margin-top: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

And finally my JavaScript:

```js
function heroHeight() {
   var heroCurHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
   heroCurHeight.style.marginTop = (window.outerHeight - 220);
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `heroCurHeight.style.marginTop = (window.outerHeight - 220) + "px"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Dynamic margin with CSS

That seems overly complicated to do with JS when you could do the same thing all in CSS (granted I don't know your use case)

```
.heroImage {
  margin-top: calc(100vh - 220px);
}
```

CSS `vh` is a percentage unit representing the height of the viewport. (auto-updates when the viewport changes size)

CSS `calc()` is intended to do math operations on multiple unit types.

*Edit:*

### If you're going to stick with Javascript...

You really need to pay attention to performance and only run the function when the user is DONE messing with the window size. This is called "debouncing" the function. Here's a [good overview](https://gomakethings.com/debouncing-your-javascript-events/) of techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the unit

```
heroCurHeight.style.marginTop = (window.outerHeight - 220) + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was in this line:

```
heroCurHeight.style.marginTop = (window.outerHeight - 220);
```

You can not set the `margin-top` without set together with some [unit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) (e.g 'px'). So, you just need to change the wrong line code to this:

```
heroCurHeight.style.marginTop = `${(window.outerHeight - 220)}px`
```

Follows a full working example:

```js
function heroHeight() {
   const heroCurHeight = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
   heroCurHeight.style.marginTop = `${(window.outerHeight - 220)}px` ;
}
```

```css
.content {
   margin-top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body onresize="heroHeight()" onload="heroHeight()">
   <div class="heroImage"></div>
   <div class="content">
      <!-- page content -->
   </div>
</body>
```